# waitpid with WUNTRACED

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel

Could someone please explain what the waitpid() call with the WUNTRACED option is used for? I understand that waitpid without any flags and -1 in the pid argument returns when a child exits. The manpage says

```
 If the WUNTRACED option is set, children of the current process 
that are stopped due to a SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, SIGTSTP, or SIGSTOP signal 
also have their status reported.
```

I do not see where this might be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `waitpid()` function doesn't let you continue the execution until you get a status report from the given pid. If that pid gets a `SIGSTOP` for example and you don't provide the function with the `WUNTRACED` option your program will still wait for a status report in `waitpid()`.